# SQLite: bulk update a 'boolean' column

Tags: java, android, sqlite, sql-update, android-sqlite

What is the standard approach to update a boolean column (i.e. a categorical binary `INTEGER` value) in a SQL (SQLite) table?

<sup>*(here binary is intended to mean an INTEGER that takes two values only: `0` and `1`, hence the quotes in the question title)*</sup>

Given a table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE types (
    id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, 
    name TEXT, 
    enabled INTEGER DEFAULT 1)
```

And a list of objects which can have an enabled/disabled state and which are represented as two lists:

```java
List<Long> idsEnabled = new ArrayList<>();
List<Long> idsDisabled = new ArrayList<>();
```

Would this be the correct way to store the enabled state (i.e. `0` or `1`)?

```java
SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();

// upd: NOT WORKING because rawQuery does NOT work for modifying data, 
// must use execSQL
db.rawQuery("UPDATE types set enabled=1 where id in (" 
    + TextUtils.join(",", idsEnabled) + ")", null);
db.rawQuery("UPDATE types set enabled=0 where id in (" 
    + TextUtils.join(",", idsDisabled) + ")", null);
```

Is there a better, more efficient, OOTB way to do this? My assumption is that updating each row one by one would be the worst case.

The question is not necessarily android-specific, although if there is some android-specific API for doing this it would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method `rawQuery()` is not the way to update the table.
It is used to return rows in the form of a `Cursor`.
In this case you must use `execSQL()`:

```
if (idsEnabled.size() > 0 || idsDisabled.size() > 0) {
    String ids1 = TextUtils.join(",", idsEnabled);
    String ids0 = TextUtils.join(",", idsDisabled);
    String sql =
            "UPDATE types " +
            "SET enabled = CASE " +
            (idsEnabled.size() > 0 ? "WHEN id IN (" + ids1 + ") THEN 1 " : "") +
            (idsDisabled.size() > 0 ? "WHEN id IN (" + ids0 + ") THEN 0 " : "") +
            "ELSE enabled " +
            "END";
    db.execSQL(sql);
}
```

The above statement uses a `CASE` expression to determine the value that will update the current value of the column.

If you want to update just a small part of the table then it would be more efficient to include a `WHERE` clause in the `UPDATE` statement, so you can omit the `ELSE` part of the `CASE` expression:

```
if (idsEnabled.size() > 0 || idsDisabled.size() > 0) {
    String ids1 = TextUtils.join(",", idsEnabled);
    String ids0 = TextUtils.join(",", idsDisabled);

    String idsAll = "";
    if (idsEnabled.size() == 0) idsAll = ids0;
    else if (idsDisabled.size() == 0) idsAll = ids1;
    else idsAll = ids1 + "," + ids0;

    String sql =
            "UPDATE types " +
            "SET enabled = CASE " +
            (idsEnabled.size() > 0 ? "WHEN id IN (" + ids1 + ") THEN 1 " : "") +
            (idsDisabled.size() > 0 ? "WHEN id IN (" + ids0 + ") THEN 0 " : " ") +
            "END " +
            "WHERE id IN (" + idsAll + ")";
    db.execSQL(sql);
}
```